# Responsive drop down menu not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, wordpress-theming

Ok so I just spent 24 hours to find out how to fix drop downs when the min-screen size is 720px :|....but I couldn't fix it :( and also it's rtl and if there were any other mistakes please tell me

HTML:

```
<header>


<!-- Navbar -->    
<nav class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-film" aria-hidden="true"></i> menu2</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="#">dropdown1</a></li>
                <li><a href="##">drowpdown2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i> menu3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> menu4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Search Box --->    
    <div class="search-div">
        <form method="get" action="/search" id="searchbox5">
            <input class="search" name="q" type="text" size="30" placeholder="Search..." />
        </form>

    </div>
</nav>
    <div class="logo-div">
       <a href="#"> <h1 class="logo-h1">LOGO</h1>
        <img class="logo-img" src="img/logo.png" onmouseover="this.src='img/rlogo.png'" onmouseout="this.src='img/logo.png'"/></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

https://blography.org/main.css

Comment: Can you make a functional JSFiddle or CodePen to more easily test this?

Comment: @aardrian [http://codepen.io/mr_no/pen/xOVMWR](http://codepen.io/mr_no/pen/xOVMWR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you used `position:absolute;` on `:hover` effect of `li` so remove the `position:absolute;` property on `:hover` effect of `li` "`.nav li:hover ul`"